# Simple webservice example for JDK 1.4

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jdk1.4

Can anyone help me to learn developing webservices with jdk 1.4?

I'm restricted to JDK 1.4, so I can't use web services which use annotation.

Comment: Apache axis 1.4 can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version of [Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/building-axis.html)  required JDK Version - 1.3.1+